# row number over partition in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I used the following query to get the result as

```
Select * from
          (
          Select M.MaterialName,L.LocationName,S.Balance,S.StockDate,ROW_NUMBER()
          over(Partition by L.LocationName,M.MaterialName order by S.StockDate desc)RN from
          StockRegister S join Locations L on S.LocationId=L.LocationId join                 
          ElectricalProducts M on M.PartNo=S.PartNo 
          where S.StockDate<=convert(date,'01-02-2014',103) and      
          substring(S.PartNo,1,2)='01' and SUBSTRING(S.PartNo,9,3)='002'
          )sr
```

the result is

```
    Material Name           Location        Qty     StockDate      RN 
    Tube LightPhilips40W    ShozhingaNal    200    2014-01-31      1
    Tube LightPhilips40W    Kottivakkam     200    2014-01-31      1
    Tube LightPhilips40W    Kottivakkam     150    2014-01-31      2
    Tube LightPhilips40W    MAChidambaramm  50     2014-01-31      1
```

from that i have to get the only the latest entry as follows

```
       Material Name           Location       Qty     StockDate      RN     
       Tube LightPhilips40W    ShozhingaNal   200     2014-01-31     1
       Tube LightPhilips40W    Kottivakkam    150     2014-01-31     2
       Tube LightPhilips40W    MAChidambaramm  50     2014-01-31     1
```

How to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this

Use `COUNT(*) OVER(Partition by L.LocationName,M.MaterialName ) CNT` this to find latest row

```
 SELECT * FROM
             (
              SELECT M.MaterialName,L.LocationName,S.Balance,S.StockDate,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by L.LocationName,M.MaterialName order by S.StockDate DESC)RN
              COUNT(*) OVER(Partition by L.LocationName,M.MaterialName ) CNT
              FROM StockRegister S JOIN Locations L ON
                                 S.LocationId=L.LocationId 
              JOIN ElectricalProducts M ON
                                 M.PartNo=S.PartNo 
              WHERE S.StockDate <= convert(date,'01-02-2014',103) AND 
              SUBSTRING(S.PartNo,1,2)='01' AND
              SUBSTRING(S.PartNo,9,3)='002'
             )AS S 
             WHERE RN = CNT
```

> Or else try below method

Since you are ordering StockDate in RowNumber by `DESC`, So latest RowNumber becomes 1. Hence you can select it by `WHERE RN = 1`

```
         SELECT * FROM
         (
          SELECT M.MaterialName,L.LocationName,S.Balance,S.StockDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by L.LocationName,M.MaterialName order by S.StockDate DESC)RN 
          FROM StockRegister S JOIN Locations L ON
                             S.LocationId=L.LocationId 
          JOIN ElectricalProducts M ON
                             M.PartNo=S.PartNo 
          WHERE S.StockDate <= convert(date,'01-02-2014',103) AND 
          SUBSTRING(S.PartNo,1,2)='01' AND
          SUBSTRING(S.PartNo,9,3)='002'
         )AS S WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: i cant use RN=1 because i need the latest entry show RN cannot be 1 it may be 2,3,4.. depends on the entris

Comment: Then You can use first method @user3234884

Comment: @user3234884 You don't bother about RN=1 because we are ordering in DESC so last RN becomes first

Comment: i need only the last RN not all,ie) if one materialname have RN as 1,2 i need only RN=2 not all

Comment: i like to show the latest entry for each location and each material

Comment: @user3234884 Yes first method will show you the latest recored based on location and material